# Removing duplicate records from a weighted relational database

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, weighted

I have a relational SQL database, derived from data returned by a Tensorflow image classifier. I believe that there are a huge number of duplicate entries in both the image table and relational table and I would like to remove them while ensuring that I don't break any relationships.

For example, this relationships table:

```
image_id | term_id | weight
1 18 0.95336
2 18 0.49187
2 25 0.35451
3 18 0.84148
3 18 0.84148
3 18 0.84148
4 18 0.84148
5 7 0.25471
```

Should become:

```
image_id | term_id | weight
1 18 0.95336
2 18 0.49187
2 25 0.35451
3 18 0.84148
5 7 0.25471
```

And this image table:

```
ID | file_path | file_name
1 /folder/ imageDog.jpg
2 /folder/ imageMouse.jpg
3 /folder/subfolder/ imageCat.jpg
4 /folder/subfolder/ imageCat.jpg
5 /folder/subfolder/ imageSnake.jpg
```

Should become:

```
ID | file_path | file_name
1 /folder/ imageDog.jpg
2 /folder/ imageMouse.jpg
3 /folder/subfolder/ imageCat.jpg
5 /folder/subfolder/ imageSnake.jpg
```

Notice that that image with ID 4 is a duplicate of 3, so the image AND it's relationships need to be deleted. I think that in some cases, relationships might be missing for some duplicated images, in which case, only the one image with relationships should be kept. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: which db you are using ?

Comment: mySQL, phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an aggregation function for obtain a single image_id  eg: min(image_id)  group by term_id, weight

```
  select min(image_id ) min_id
    , term_id 
    , weight
  from my_table  
  group by term_id, weight
```

and if you want delete the path not related  to the min_id result you could use

```
delete  from your_file_path_table 
where ID  not in (
  select min(image_id ) 
     from my_table  
    group by term_id, weight
)
```